# Get the Oracle cursor with Node and TypeORM

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, typeorm, node-oracledb, node.js-typeorm

I have this Oracle stored procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE STORED_TEST(
      PARAM_1     IN NVARCHAR2
      REF_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      MESSAGE    OUT VARCHAR2
      );
```

I am calling it from node (TypeScript) application with TypeORM:

Imports:

```js
import { dataSource } from '../utils/database';
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
```

Call:

```js
const sql = 'BEGIN PKG_TEST.STORED_TEST(:PARAM_1, :REF_CURSOR, :MESSAGE); END;';

const result = await dataSource.query(
  sql, [
  { val: param1, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, type: oracledb.VARCHAR },
  { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR },
  { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.VARCHAR }]
);

console.log("result:", result);
```

I got this result in console:

```
result: [
  ResultSet {
    _rowCache: [],
    _processingStarted: false,
    _convertedToStream: false,
    _allowGetRowCall: false,
    _parentObj: Connection {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _dbObjectClasses: {},
      _pool: [Pool],
      _newSession: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  'OK'
]
```

How can I retrieve the rows of this cursor?

Comment: Is the answer [in the documentation](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#ref-cursor-bind-parameters)?

Comment: No, it isn't the same, my connection is from TypeORM datasource, I don't have outBinds.cursor property, I think it can be get by some casting or function of the result, but I don't know what

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are printing has the two OUT bind variables already in it: the REF CURSOR has been returned as a ResultSet (the first value in the result array), and the OUT bind message is "OK".

To get data from the ResultSet, refer to [examples/refcursor.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/refcursor.js) on GitHub.

In your case, try something like:

```
    const resultSet = result[0];
    const rows = await resultSet.getRows();  // no parameter means get all rows
    console.log(rows);

    await resultSet.close();                  // always close the ResultSet
```

If the number of rows is huge, you may want to loop over `getRows()`: see the example in GitHub.

Comment: That don't work, I already tried it. [Here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9340#issuecomment-1236174565) it says that for advanced cases use the oracledb native. So I solved it with oracledb, with typeORM is not possible.

Comment: Your output is clearly showing a ResultSet so it should be possible somehow in typeORM.  But without more information e.g. about the error we can't comment.